# Debugging htcondor issue running python script

Tags: python, condor

I am submitting a python script to condor. When condor runs it it gets
an import error. Condor runs it as
/var/lib/condor/execute/dir_170475/condor_exec.exe. If I manually copy
the python script to the execute machine and put it in the same place
and run it, it does not get an import error. I am wondering how to
debug this.

How can I see the command line condor uses to run it? Can the file
copied to /var/lib/condor/execute/dir_170475/condor_exec.exe be
retained after the failure so I can see it? Any other suggestions on
how to debug this?

Comment: Hello, what exact error message do you get? Is it your file that cannot be imported or some other file you imported? Does it work for other python files?

Comment: The error I get is `ImportError: No module named modules`. modules is one of our modules, The dir that it is in exists and is in python's sys.path. Could it be a permission issue? I see in the execute machine's StarterLog.slot1: `Running job as user nobody`. I wanted to try running it as nobody but I cannot su to that user. How can I emulate exactly what condor does?

Answer (score 1):

You can simply run an interactive job (basically just a job with sleep or cat as command) and do ssh_to_job to run it.

Generally you need to set-up your python environment on the compute node, it is best to have a venv and activate it inside your start script.